# Tor Browser will not browse anything

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, mac

I recently downloaded Tor on my MAC and it connected just fine but the browser is stuck on the "Congratulations!" page. I can't even go to Startpage. The tab just says "connecting..." but then it times out. I turned off my firewall and the clock is adjusted correctly. What do I do to become able to browse?

Comment: What page are you trying to open? A normal webpage or a hidden service? Does entering a search term work for you? Please edit your question and give some more information.